# How to Track user action for breadcrumb in react native?

Tags: react-native

Trying to create a breadcrumb module where all the user action will be stored. Problem is how do I track the user actions in React native as a third party module. Need to know the UIElements and their respective callback functions.

Example : User has clicked on Button X in Screen Y.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think react refs might be useful

Comment: Don't want to touch present code base, need to act as third party.

Comment: this is a tough one honestly. Probably doing some prototype changes to React itself would help?(https://www.javascriptjanuary.com/blog/extending-react)

Comment: Will try some other means to get them, MessageQueue does some spy work. Need to understand how that works. May be I can get some clue to peep into the messaging code.